# Error "pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError" while Creating Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I am trying to create a Dataframe from the rows of another Dataframe while iterating. Below is my code:

```
df_cols = ["categoryname", "issueid", "module", "type", "description", "sourcefile", "line", "description"]

mydataframe = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in nw.iterrows():
    if (row['issueid'] in nw1['issueid'].values):
        print(str(row['issueid']) + "is present")
    else:
        print(str(row['issueid']) + " is not present")
        # mydataframe=mydataframe.append(row, ignore_index=True)
        new_df = pd.DataFrame([row], columns=df_cols)          #ERROR
        #mydataframe = pd.concat([mydataframe, new_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

For the line:

```
  new_df = pd.DataFrame([row], columns=df_cols)
```

I am getting error:

```
 pandas.errors.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

Comment: What is `nw1`?  and you should try not to `iterrows` as this is anti-pattern for pandas. If you want to filter the dataframe, use `nw = nw[~nw.issueid.isin(...)]`, something like this.

Comment: @Emma, I fixed it, by a converting the tuple to list and then create the dataframe

Comment: cool, although do you get about the `iterrows`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by converting the tuple "row" to list and passing as an argument to the Dataframe as below:

```
df_cols = ["categoryname", "issueid", "module", "type", "description", "sourcefile", "line", "description"]

mydataframe = pd.DataFrame()
for index, row in nw.iterrows():
    if (row['issueid'] in nw1['issueid'].values):
        print(str(row['issueid']) + "is present")
    else:
        print(str(row['issueid']) + " is not present")
        # mydataframe=mydataframe.append(row, ignore_index=True)
        new_df = pd.DataFrame([list(row)], columns=df_cols)          #Works Now
        #mydataframe = pd.concat([mydataframe, new_df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```